# .NET Core 2.1 и директивы препроцессора

Tags: c#, .net

Прочитал, что для того, чтобы использовать выражение #if RELEASE нужно в настройках проекта установить в режиме релиза значение RELEASE в textbox Conditional compilation symbols. Однако в настройках проекта ничего не стоит и отжат checkbox define DEBUG constant, при этом работает как #if RELESE, так и #if DEBUG. В чем может быть подвох?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уже [больше года](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/2733) не могут пофиксить :-)

Comment: В студии в свойствах проекта для Release умолчанию вписано RELEASE;NETCOREAPP2_0;. Вы точно для Release проверяете? Там комбик Configuration есть прямо на этой вкладке, и он не синхронизируется с активной билд конфигурацией :)

Comment: @PashaPash♦, да, точно

Comment: У меня в свежесозданном проекте работает правильно - при компиляции код выбрасывается. Можете привести минимальный код для воспроизведения (cs-файл и файл проекта)?

Comment: Вот ссылка: https://github.com/vadim-bondaruk/directives-test. Настройки проекта как на скриншоте, условие #if RELEASE срабатывает.